# Display the Elements in an Array One at a Time using GetKeyDown in Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, image, unity-game-engine

I'm essentially trying to make a slideshow in Unity 2018. I want to display a new image every time, say, the right arrow key is pressed. I could do this by loading a whole new scene every time the right arrow key is pressed, but I could have potentially thousands of scenes (it's a pretty long slideshow!), and I wondered if there wasn't a more elegant solution. I thought the best way to accomplish this would be with an array of images and a simple for loop to move to the next index in the array.

So I created a few image GameObjects and a script that puts them into an array. The problem I have is that whenever I press the right arrow key, the for loop I've implemented shoots right the way through to the end of the array and thus I only see the last image. I want to be able to go through each image one by one as I press the right arrow key.

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LoadImage : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private Image newImage;
[SerializeField] Image[] nextImage;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    GetNextImage();
} 

private Image GetNextImage()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nextImage.Length; i++)
        {
            newImage = nextImage[i];
            newImage.enabled = true;
        }
    }
    return newImage;
}
}
```

Here are a few images of my Unity work space while the game is stopped and while it's running:

[The game is stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTLFC.png),

[The game is running but I haven't pressed the right arrow key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx6iY.png),

[The game is running and I've pressed the right arrow key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWJAG.png).

As you can see in the last image instead of moving to element_1 and staying there until I press the right arrow again, it iterates all the way through until element_2.

As I'm sure you can tell, I'm a novice, and any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your for loop always start with 0 because i = 0 and ends at the end of your image array.
But you don t need the loop.
You have to remember the number of your current image. This example shows how it works in one direction.

```
    int currentImageIndex = 0;
    private Image GetNextImage()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && currentImageIndex < nextImage.Length)
        {
            //Take image on current postion
            newImage = nextImage[currentImageIndex]; 
            newImage.enabled = true;
            //Add one to currentImageIndex 
            currentImageIndex++;
        }
    }
```